# Python Windows Explorer Force Refresh

Tags: python-3.x, windows, winapi

I have code, but it doesn't do what I want.  I'm trying to delete thumbnail cache via Python script.  If I have cache and explorer's open, some of the .db files won't delete because they're in use by explorer.  Anyway, in my experimenting, the only way to do it is to change the advanced folder setting for displaying icons/thumbnails, and then restarting explorer.  I can change the setting via script in the registry and then restart explorer.  BUT, restarting explorer halts the script.  So, I don't know.  I also tried changing the setting and then sending the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message via SendMessageTimeout().  That didn't do the trick.

So, anyone have any idea how to unlock files (that are safe to delete) from explorer (this could also pertain to other in-use files) without restarting it?  Also, I understand this is a sort of dumb project, but I have my reasons for doing it and it's what I want to do.

Comment: I've continued investigating and it seems terminating handles to the file is the only way to delete them.  I found "Handle" by Sysinternals, used it, and the thumbnail cache handles aren't closing.  Windows REALLY doesn't want those files deleted until it says it's okay to.  How does Disk Cleanup do it?  How does CCleaner do it?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have cache and explorer's open, some of the .db files won't
> delete because they're in use by explorer.

Because `thumbcache.dll` still has an open handle to the local thumbs.db file and does not currently implement a mechanism to release the handle to the file in a more dynamic and timely fashion.

They are only generated for compatibility with outdated applications, and are not required for Windows operations.

To work around the issue, enable User Group Policy setting for "Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files":

Refer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2025703?

[image: 1]

Also, you can directly edit the registry. Refer:[Let me fix it myself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/renaming-a-network-folder-fails#let-me-fix-it-myself)

Related: ["The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows Explorer"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed3a112e-df02-41b7-aace-09707113ae47/fix-bug-thumbsdb-quotthe-action-cant-be-completed-because-the-file-is-open-in-windows?forum=W8ITProPreRel)

Comment: Okay, so how would I implement that in code, without having to change the Group Policy settings?  That registry key is not present.  I searched the whole registry for that value and it's not there.  The GP setting is there but says it's for Vista, not newer (I'm on latest 10).  Unless that means it was implemented in Vista and newer OSs?

Comment: @malonn Almost all solutions point to changing the group policy. On my windows 10, I can Enable "Turn off..." in the group policy, this operation will automatically generate the `DisableThumbsDBOnNetworkFolders` key in the registry. If you need to use the programming method, you can create a .reg file, then refer to [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/cant-stop-thumbsdb-caching/24b34cc2-dd86-415e-b1d9-5693215c1606?tm=1466006240429), copy some necessary command lines, and then use `ShellExecute` to execute it.

Comment: I will implement this in code for experimental purposes, but I must say, my problem was with the thumbnailcache_xx.db files, not thumbs.db.  They are not referring to the same files are they?  Thumbs.db is from older version of Windows.  Thumbcache.dll may yet have an open handle to a thumbnailcache_xx.db file, and I will see if these registry settings allow me to delete the thumbnailcache_xx.db files, but it doesn't sound like the exact same thing.

Comment: @malonn Beginning with Windows Vista, thumbnail previews are stored in a centralized location on the system. This provides the system with access to images independent of their location, and addresses issues with the locality of Thumbs.db files. The cache is stored at %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer as a number of files with the label thumbcache_xxx.db (numbered by size); as well as an index used to find thumbnails in each sized database.

Comment: @malonn You also need to `Uncheck "Display file icon on thumbnails"` , refer: [Unable To delete thumbs.db](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/unable-to-delete-thumbsdb/476dbfa7-6cd8-43a7-b162-c9228edd3049). I can use `del "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache*.db"  /a`(cmd command)  to delete thumbnailcache_xx.db files. When deleting these files, do not open the file explorer. As you said, file explorer may be using their handle.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Strive Sun.  I have found a way to delete the cache files via restarting explorer and that settings you mentioned.  I feel it to be sorta hacky, but it works.

Comment: @malonn You are welcome. If the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)